# Android AppCompat Library usage

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I found on many blogs and tutorials links, where clearily written to support AppCompat Library we should use ActionBarActivity to extend Class instead of normal Activity.

So its clear to me, but i have few doubts in my mind regarding extending ActionBarActivity.

**Questions are:**

1. *what if my class extends Fragment  (is there i need to extends ActionBarActivity) while using AppCompat Library?*
2. *what if my class extends ListActivity (is there i need to extends ActionBarActivity) while using AppCompat Library (if 'yes' so how ?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` so you can use fragments with it

2) Instead of using `ListActivity` you have to add a `ListFragment` to your `ActionBarActivity` (or `FragmentActivity`). You can add it to `android.R.id.content` so it occupies the whole screen.

Comment: so finally i replaced Fragment with ActionBarActivity and it works fine for me